# PHP Function 'return' not returning

Tags: php, function

This is a bit of an oddity for me. PHP is my forte, and I can normally figure out any issue I encounter.

I have a custom framework that I have been using for years. I have taken it upon myself to rewrite it, and I'm doing everything essentially the same that I was before. The problem lies in the following construct:

```
function ModPages_GetPage() {
    $page = ModPages_GetPageByName($_GET['page_name']);
    if($page != false) {
        include(TPL_DIR.'pages/pages.view.php');
    } else {
        ErrorMessage('Invalid Page', 'The selected page could not be found.');
    }
}


function ModPages_GetPageByName($page_name = null) {
    $db = new Database;
    $query = '
        SELECT *
        FROM pages
        WHERE page_name = "'.CleanStr($page_name).'"
            AND page_enabled = "yes"
        LIMIT 1
        ';
    $page = $db->GetRow($query);

    return $page;
}
```

This code is being called with 'home' for the value of `$_GET['page_name']`. The call to `ModPages_GetPageByName()` is working fine, but the value of `$page` in `ModPages_GetPage()` isn't getting set. Matter of fact, any debugging statements thrown in after that call are failing to display anything.

I have `display_errors` set to `on`, and `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL`. I get a couple notices from my Database class, but that's it.

Running the script at a shell fails to produce any errors. When using `strace`, I do see the process spits out an 'exit_group(255)'.

This one has me quite baffled. I could sure use some direction on this.

Comment: It sounds like you've checked that, if you `var_dump ($page)` just before `return $page`, you see the expected value (an array or something more complicated?). Does the `Database` class have a destructor that might go awry?

Comment: And have you actually tried **debugging** it? Ie. use Zend Debugger or xdebug, set a breakpoint and step through your code...

Comment: You should have at least tried `var_dump($page)` by now; what is the output?

Comment: grossvogel and meagar, if you read my responses to the answers below you'll know that I have tried inspecting $page. Everywhere up to the 'return $page' it is fine, but in the calling function it is completely empty, not even a 'null' value.

Comment: What happens if you change the return to `return array('foo');`. I'm trying to eliminate the possibility that what `$db->GetRow()` returns is a reference that is being garbage collected somehow. How is `GetRow()` declared? What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Should be `if ($page !== false) ...`

Comment: Try forcing a copy of the array before returning. PHP array assignment is a copy, but until one of the copies is changed they are really the same thing -- it's a lazy copy. I'm wondering if the array created in `GetRow()` is destroyed when the function returns, leaving `$page` dangling. Try `return array_merge($page);` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Skudd. That's why I said 'It sounds like you've checked...'. Anyway, what is `$page` when it's fine? A string, array, class instance? I, like @Craig, think the problem might have to do with your Database class.

Comment: What is this `Database`? You didn't show us what it does. My guess would be an exception being thrown from `GetRow`, likely due to invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While some of you have put extra effort into responding to this, nobody has been able to see the full picture, even given the details I have provided. I have been unable to trace the issue back to its source, but have moved on to a different project.

Comment: too bad, that you weren't able to figure it out. i just ran into a similar issue. :-(

Comment: this can probably have multiple causes. i just figured out, that my problem was related to a wrong parameter i provided for the constructor of an extension (mongodb). i still wonder, why php just died with a exit_group(255) instead of reporting an error.

Comment: This is quite an old question but I had a similar issue. The problem was that PDO (I am assuming you are using this) was accessing a different database outside of the user account with the localhost settings and even though the query ran correctly it refused to return the result even if it returned a manually assigned array it would not return the result. Updating the settings to a database on the user account associated with the account fixed the issue. This may not be the same problem but it certainly sounds like it.

Comment: Nope, it wasn't PDO. It has been so long since I posted this that I can't even remember if I solved it or not. I've since discovered how to use XDebug, and would love to revisit this issue and see exactly where it's failing and why, but that's not really going to happen since I don't even have that code or environment at my disposal any longer.

Answer (score 1):

I would think it's your query, shouldn't you just return the page name instead of star? as star (*) would return an array which is probably being passed back as the value? just my guess.

```
$query = '
        SELECT *
        FROM pages
        WHERE page_name = "'.CleanStr($page_name).'"
            AND page_enabled = "yes"
        LIMIT 1
        ';
```

if you do a print_r on the $page return I would think it should be an array

```
$page = $db->GetRow($query);
echo "Page:<pre>".print_r($page,true)."</pre><br />\n";
```

Then maybe return something like this

```
return $page['page_name_field'];
```

Comment: The purpose of the function is to return the entire record from the pages table. After the query runs, the Database class returns the page properly. It's the call to ModPages_GetPageByName() that isn't returning properly.

Answer (score 0):

ok before we get to a solution can we first make sure that before setting the $page variable, first just echo `$_GET['page_name']` to see if there is a value being received.

**PK**

Comment: that would make the GetPage function recursive, and that function doesn't take any arguments...

Comment: If you don't have an answer, please ask for more information in comments, not answers. Thanks.

Comment: yes you are right. ok thank you for the heads up. i wont do this again then. i guess this would be considered as littering in the stackoverflow community. sorry

Comment: The query is functioning properly. The return $page is what's failing. Everything up to that point is assigned a value as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Does your script stop right after your database call, or just doesn't display any output?

If the first is true, then it looks like a fatal error. With `E_ALL`, it should be displayed, are you sure both display_errors and error_reporting are as you say *at that point*, and that the GetRow function doesn't alter them in any way? If so, maybe there's something in the Apache error log (PHP errors are sometimes logged there).

If the latter is true I'm thinking about an exception being thrown in a method that is being called, and caught in a higher level function. To check this you can put the database call (ie: the point where things go wrong) inside a try/catch block and see if you reach the catch block.

Comment: If I print_r($page) before the return, all is well and working as expected. If I print_r($page) after the call to ModPages_GetPageByName(), it's empty.

Comment: One thing comes to mind: an extended method. Check if ModPages_GetPageByName isn't defined in a extending class.

Comment: To check more precisely how your code flows, do a backtrace after the function call: `debug_print_backtrace()` shows you exactly which functions were called/executed.

Answer (score 0):

I would try following:

- replace $_GET with $_REQUEST (maybe your form is using POST?)
- do a **print_r** to check contents of your variables.
- use mysql_error to view any errors, or print your mysql query in your browser, copy/paste it in phpmyadmin, is it returning anything? error.. data?
- something similar happend to me once, my framework was encoded in ANSI and my calling php file was UTF8+BOM...  I changed everything to UTF8+BOM and it worked.
- try also different browser, I know it might not be a browser problem, but it might be that your script is cached somewhere.
- are you using some caching? like eaccelerator?

Comment: "The call to ModPages_GetPageByName() is working fine, but the value of $page in ModPages_GetPage() isn't getting set." -- At all points in ModPages_GetPageByName() the function is working properly. It's only after the call to ModPages_GetPageByName() in ModPages_GetPage() that there's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are those functions in a class?  If so, you will need $page = $this->ModPages_GetPageByName().

Also I would echo out the argument and the sql statment in ModPages_GetPageByName(). This way you can verify that it isn't a SQL error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure why your code isn't working, but I can make some suggestions that might help in locating the error.

The first thing I notice is you don't check that $db actually contains a valid database.  I don't know the details of your Database object but I'm assuming there's some mechanism in there for checking if it's actually connected to the database.  You should use that to determine if the database is connected before running queries on it.

```
$db = new Database ();
if ($db -> isConnected ())
{
    $query = 'SELECT * (etc etc etc)';
    // ...
}
else
{
    // Put some kind of DB connection error notification or throw an exception here
}
```

Just on a stylistic note, you don't need to store the results of your DB lookup before returning it, unless you're planning on doing some processing on the result before returning it.  You can just return the lookup directly.  Of course that's just a stylistic choice, but it saves a line or two :)

```
return ($db->GetRow($query));
```

After you run your getpage function, I'd strongly recommend var_dump()ing the result.  Even if your function returned NULL, you'll still see this in the var_dump.  If in doubt, dump it out :).  I'd also recommend installing xdebug to make the var_dump output more readable.

```
$page = ModPages_GetPageByName($_GET['page_name']);
var_dump ($page);
```

I would also strongly recommending var_dumping your query before you execute just to make absolutely sure that you're running the query you think you're running.  Copy and paste the outputted query into sqlyog or phpmyadmin or whatever you use for interactive access to your database and make sure it returns what you think it should return.

Other things to check, is the page you're trying to return actually set page_enabled='yes'?  Does the page_enabled column actually store the value as 'yes', or is it a bool or an integer or something else?  Is magic quotes enabled or disabled?  If they're in one state when you think they're in the other they can cause confusion.  Are errors actually being reported to the browser?  Add a line at the top of your script that's guaranteed to fail just to make sure, like an attempted foreach on an integer.  If you don't see an error, then maybe error reporting isn't configured properly.  I know those are obvious questions but I also know how easy it is to overlook the obvious if you're not getting what you expect out of a query.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure $page is not set, or is it just that your debug instructions don't print anything? Try logging to a file or a database instead; maybe your code triggered output buffering or something like that.

Also, you are calling ModPages_GetPageByName before declaring it. That is usually okay, but might not be in special circumstances (e.g. when the code is wrapped in an if block). Try swapping the two.

Also, check your environment and disable opcode caching and other possible error sources. APC for example can call the old version of the script long after you changed the PHP file.